# google coral - nmtui not showing wifi in "Activate a connection" tap

Tags: google-coral

I'm learning google coral and I got a internet connection problem.

[Google coral guideline](https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board/get-started/#connect-internet), they said there should be network list under wi-fi(wlan0).
But my case, I couldn't find any available wi-fi network list in [activate a connection tap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6p3H.png) .

As I check the connection by using 'nmcli connection show', there was no wlan0 device for [wifi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCYGH.jpg).

Is there any way to fix it and make wireless connection for the coral board ?
I'm using ubuntu20.04 LTS by WSL1.

Comment: Did you try to reflash the board ?

Comment: nope, I got this board from school and all the board settings were installed already. I'll give it a try and reply afterr, thank you!

Comment: Try to reflash the board once.